# File upload into Unix box using Angular 2 - what is url and how it works?

Tags: angular

I am getting a problem with using the URL in an **Angular 2** upload.

Is this any service URL or FTP URL, and how can I upload into my local system like `C:\test\upload`?

If the URL is a service, how do I do this in Spring?

How can I upload a file into a Unix box?

```
public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url:''});
```

Comment: i have gone through that but didnt get my answer

Comment: How can I upload file into unix box using angular2?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can use **XMLHttpRequest** to upload a file from Angular 2, get the file in the backend (like Python, PHP, etc.) and store the file whatever the location you want.

**Example:**

```
FileUploadService(file_to_upload) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let url = 'backend/upload';

    let res = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let formData: any = new FormData();
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        formData.append(file_to_upload.type, file_to_upload.file)
        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        xhr.send(formData);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                let respone = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(respone);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The above code is useful to send a file from frontend to backend, and to store a file wherever you want from the backend.

The explanation to executing the code is given below.

> **file_to_upload:** This is the file you get it from the file input
>
> **file_to_upload.type:** This refers to the type of file
>
> **file_to_upload.file:** This refers to the file object

Comment: Thanks Hari.. we are not allowed to use Python or Php is thr any other way can we implement backend service like in Java if possible could you please share some examples.

Comment: i am sure we can implement backend service in java but more i want to know service how it will recive a request and it proecess the file ? Please share some examples if possible?